# jquery click does not work although I've enclosed in document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, click

jquery click not working. Although, this issue has been discussed a lot, I can not find an answer that solves the problem for me. I have enclosed jQuery code in $(document).ready but vainly.

here is the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="triliza01.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.1.11.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

           p1=new lPlayer("x.png");
           p2=new lPlayer("o.jpg");
           p1.setOponent(p2);
           p2.setOponent(p1);
           theWinner=play(p1);

        }); // end of ready( ) function
    </script> 
</head>
<body>

        <table>
            <tr id="zRaw">
                <td id="z0">

                </td>
                <td id="z1">

                </td>
                <td id="z2">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="fRaw">
                <td id="f0">
                </td>
                <td id="f1">
                </td>
                <td id="f2">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="sRaw">
                <td id="s0">
                </td>
                <td id="s1">
                </td>
                <td id="s2">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

</body>
```

and here is the javascript

```
function Player (sign) {
    this.sign=sign;
    this.oponent=null;
    this.setOponent=function (player) {
        this.oponent=player;
    }; 
}

function lPlayer (sign) {
    this.base=Player;
    this.base(sign);

    this.move=function (board) {

        do {
            for (var i in board) {    
                if (i.charAt(0)!=='#') continue;
                //alert(board[i]);
                $(i).click( function() {
                    if (board[i]==="none") {
                        board[i]=sign;
                        return i;
                    }
                } );
            }
        } while (true);       
   }; 
}

lPlayer.prototype=new Player;


function Board() {
    this["#z0"]="none";
    this["#z1"]="none";
    this["#z2"]="none";

    this["#f0"]="none";
    this["#f1"]="none";
    this["#f2"]="none";

    this["#s0"]="none";
    this["#s1"]="none";
    this["#s2"]="none";

    this.full= function() {
        cnt=0;
        for (var i in this) {
            if (this.hasOwnProperty(i)) //check it ??
                if (this[i]==="none") cnt++;
        }
        return 9-cnt;
    };

    this.autoMove=function(sign) {
        for (var i in this) {
            if (this.hasOwnProperty(i)) 
                if (this[i]==="none") {
                    this[i]=sign;
                    this.set(i,sign);
                }
        }
    };

    this.set=function(id, sign) {
        $(id).css('background-image', 'url("'+sign+'")');
        $(id).css('background-repeat', 'no-repeat');
        $(id).css('background-size', '100% 100%');
    };

    this.win=function(player) {
        s=player.sign;
        if ((this["#z0"]===s && this["#z1"]===s && this["#z2"]===s) || 
            (this["#f0"]===s && this["#f1"]===s && this["#f2"]===s) ||
            (this["#s0"]===s && this["#s1"]===s && this["#s2"]===s) ||
            (this["#z0"]===s && this["#f0"]===s && this["#s0"]===s) ||
            (this["#z1"]===s && this["#f1"]===s && this["#s1"]===s) ||
            (this["#z2"]===s && this["#f2"]===s && this["#s2"]===s) ||
            (this["#z0"]===s && this["#f1"]===s && this["#s2"]===s) ||
            (this["#z2"]===s && this["#f1"]===s && this["#s0"]===s)) return player;
        return null;    
    };

    this.winner=function(player) {
        theWinner=this.win(player);
        if (theWinner!==null) return theWinner;
        return this.win(player.oponent);
    };
 }

function play(player) {
    board=new Board();
    theWinner=null;
    current=player;
    do {
        var id;
        if (board.full()===8) board.autoMove(current.sign);
        else {
           id=current.move(board); 
           board.set(id,current.sign);
        }

        current=current.oponent;
        theWinner=board.winner(current);   
    } while ((theWinner===null) && (board.full()<9));
    return theWinner;
}
```

The problem is that in method move of lPlayer I was expecting click to respond but it does not.

I also enclose the css file

```
body {
    position:fixed;
    left:0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    top:0px;
    background-color:#666600;
}
td {
    border: 1px solid darkslategray;

    } 

table {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#ff33cc;
}
```

Any help is welcomed!
Thank you!

Comment: where is click event?

Comment: it's buried in there. you must be getting a console error I would assume?

Comment: I don't see any click event in your script. Enclose your script logic in $( "#whatYouWantToBeClicked" ).click(function() {   });

Comment: $(i).click its there

Comment: I am new in Javascript. I'm not sure whether I receive or not a console error.

Answer (score 0):

With your logic

```
$(i).click( function() {
                if (board[i]==="none") {
                    board[i]=sign;
                    return i;
                }
```

you only bind the click event handler to the click event of the i-element. If you want to fire it manually, you need to call click without parameters:

```
$(i).click()
```

And of course your handler needs to already be bound at this moment.

EDIT:
Your code does the following:

1. Go through your elements
2. If an element does not begin with "#" ignore it.
3. Assign click handler to all other elements.
4. Start again with 1.

Why do you want to assign the click handler again and again? Once per element is completely sufficient. It will get called as soon as the user clicks on the element - every time the user clicks on the element. In your case you create an infinite loop and your code will stop working.

Comment: What I want is to react when element with id i is clicked

Comment: Can you elaborate on your problem? In your post you state that you expected the the click to respond. But it won't respond since you bind the handler to the event in the move method. Binding means you tell the element what to do WHEN it is clicked. It won't do it right away. It still waits for the click. Manually fireing the event can be achieved by .click() - without parameters.

Comment: I do not want to trigger the element by code. The element is triggered by the user. This

Comment: I do not want to trigger the element by code. The element is triggered by the user. This code is a tic tac toe game that I am trying to develop. Elements that may be clicked are the 9 td elements that compose the tic tac toe board. I am trying to modify their image when they are clicked. I tried with debugger and everything seems to run correctly except that click does not triggered although user clicks on corresponding elements.

Comment: ok, I realize now that my approach is wrong. I will rewrite the code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is an **infinite loop** in your code. Impossible to test it.
And reading your code, i think that it doesn't return the right `id` of the element, that why this click doesn't work

Comment: it returns the right id as I have checked it. The loop is not infinite if click works.